# How to use Beautiful Soup 4 to find attribute

Tags: python, html, parsing, attributes, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse html like the following:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class data-row="0">
        <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class data-row="1">
        <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="thead over_theader" data-row="2">
        <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="thead" data-row="3">
        <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class data-row="4">
        <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class data-row="5">
        <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to obtain all `tr` tags (and their children) where `class` is not specified.  For the example above, that means I want the `tr` tags where `data-row` is not 2 or 3.

How do I do this using Beautiful Soup 4?

I tried

```
tableBody = soup.findAll('tbody')
rows = tableBody[0].findAll(attrs={"class":""})
```

but this returned a type `bs4.element.ResultSet` of length 8 (i.e. it included the `tr` children with `td` tags) when I wanted a `bs4.element.ResultSet` of length 4 (one for each `tr` tag with `class = ""`).

Answer (score 0):

Your method actually works for me when I specify the `tr` tag name:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = """
... <tbody>
...     <tr class data-row="0">
...         <td align="right"></td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr class data-row="1">
...         <td align="right"></td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr class="thead over_theader" data-row="2">
...         <td align="right"></td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr class="thead" data-row="3">
...         <td align="right"></td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr class data-row="4">
...         <td align="right"></td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr class data-row="5">
...         <td align="right"></td>
...     </tr>
... </tbody>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
>>> len(soup.find_all("tr", class_=""))
4
```

Alternatively, you can use a `tr[class=""]` [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
>>> len(soup.select('tr[class=""]'))
4
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_all` will, by default, search recursively.  So the `td` tags are valid matches.

[Docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#recursive):

> If you call `mytag.find_all()`, Beautiful Soup will examine all the descendants of `mytag`: its children, its children’s children, and so on. If you only want Beautiful Soup to consider direct children, you can pass in `recursive=False`

So you might write, for example:

```
tableBody = soup.findAll('tbody')
rows = tableBody[0].find_all(attrs={"class":""}, recursive=False)

print(len(rows))
for r in rows:
    print('---')
    print(r)
```

Output:

```
4
---
<tr class="" data-row="0">
<td align="right"></td>
</tr>
---
<tr class="" data-row="1">
<td align="right"></td>
</tr>
---
<tr class="" data-row="4">
<td align="right"></td>
</tr>
---
<tr class="" data-row="5">
<td align="right"></td>
</tr>
```